# Abolition vs. Abolishment

Tags: meaning, word-choice, nouns, suffixes, derivational-morphology

At times I have caught myself writing the noun form of *abolish* as "abolishment" and then pausing before realizing it should really be "abolition". Even as I type my spellchecker tells me that "abolishment" is wrong, but I know it isn't, it's just rarely used. The website [grammarist](http://grammarist.com/usage/abolishment-abolition/) has this to say

> **Abolishment** vs. **abolition**
>   *Abolishment* appears in many dictionaries and is not considered incorrect, but *abolition* is preferred in all modern varieties of English. Both nouns mean the act of doing away with something, and neither has any meanings it does not share with the other.
>
> Both words date from the early 16th century (soon after *abolish* came
>   to English from French roots), but *abolition* has always been more
>   common, and it now appears about ten times as often as *abolishment*.
>   Some writers reserve *abolishment* for senses unrelated to slavery, but
>   the distinction is unnecessary.

Nevertheless, I would like to know *why* the most common noun form is *abolition*. If I look at other verbs ending *-ish* it seems that the suffix *-ment* is preferred to make nouns.

- **abolish**+ **-ment** (rare)
- **accomplish**+ **-ment**
- **astonish**+ **-ment**
- **banish**+ **-ment**
- **establish**+ **-ment**
- **demolish**+ **-ment** (but that's considered [archaic](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demolishment#English))
- **malnourish**+ **-ment**
- **vanish** + **-ment**

Curiously, Oxford Online Dictionaries lists *only* the noun *abolishment* in its entry for *[abolish](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abolish)*, although it does have a separate entry for [abolition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/abolition). Is there a reason for this?

- Why was/is the term *abolition* preferred to *abolishment*?
- Considering the very many verbs that ending in *-ish*, why is the noun form *abolition*?

(I know "why" questions are nigh impossible to answer but I tend to see patterns and  **aboli**+ ***-tion*** appears to be an exception)

Comment: Note: *ablution* is a whole nother word entirely ;)

Comment: And now demolition and abolition have the same forms, making abolition not quite as exceptional. (as is admonition v admonishment).

Comment: @frank well post an answer. The abolition and abolishment conundrum has always bothered me a little. Good find with *admonish*!

Comment: I don't have an answer (off the top of my head) - I suspect it's to do with the French though, I was just giving you a bit more ammunition for the -ishment to -ition change.

Comment: [List of words ending in -ishment](http://www.wordwaldo.com/ending-with/ishment)

Comment: Malnourish is also a -ishment to -ition albeit a bit of a bigger shift to malnutrition.

Comment: In general, "-tion" is the fact of it; *-ment* is the act of it. HTH. *Abolish-(x)* is no exception or special case. Please redirect the research towards usage and progressively understanding the differences in meaning. Oxford is right in listing *abolishment* as a derivation from and subsidiary of *abolish*, while providing an independent entry for *abolition*.

Comment: "Abolition" is shorter and easier to say.  Why would it *not* be the more popular form of two words that mean essentially the same thing?

Comment: Besides, "abolition" was the form picked by the abolition movement which started pretty much simultaneously with the words appearing.

Comment: @HotLicks  allow me to disagree, if you're a native speaker it's easy enough but knowing where the stress lies in **/abəˈlɪʃ(ə)n/** is not a given. The main stress could be on the second syllable. It's easy to get it wrong. As for it being shorter, I suppose that's a reason.

Comment: @Kris so you are saying that the two terms have a (subtle) different meaning?

Comment: Well, words aren't invented/selected for non-native speakers.

Comment: @HotLicks have you never mispronounced a word, even when you were a child, especially if you found it in a book? Pronunciation is a problem even for native speakers.

Comment: A whole lot of a difference in meaning, in fact, in vulnerable contexts.

Comment: @Kris a "whole lot" so you disagree with the website grammarist, which I posted.

Comment: Perhaps. I wasn't referring to anyone's take on it, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is most likely that "abolition" is the more common form due in large part to its association with the "abolition movement".

France was one of the earlier countries to abolish slavery within its borders, and [Société des amis des Noirs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_of_the_Friends_of_the_Blacks) was one active group in the movement in France.

The picture on that web page refers to (pardon my French) *L'Assemblée Nationale pour L'Abolition de la Traite des Noirs* and is dated 1790.  Clearly "abolition" was the preferred term in France, and that preference would have transferred to England.

[image: Adresse A Assemblee Nationale pour L'Abolition de la Traite des Noirs]

Further, those advocating abolition in England and the US were "abolitionists".  It would have been a mouthfull to call them "abolishmentists".

The main reason one might choose "abolishment" over "abolition" (aside from the subtle difference in meaning) is that "abolition" is associated with the movement to end slavery, and thus might be confusing or distracting when used to refer to a different process.  But this confusion is not likely in native English speakers, unless the context contributes to the confusion.

Comment: +1, for the nuance- It would have been a mouthfull to call them "abolishmentists".

Answer (score 6):

According to The **N**ew **Fowler** Modern English Usage -

> "abolishment and abolition" both entered the language in the 16c. For
> two centuries they coexisted as synonyms (used of sins, faith, guilt,
> and other abstract concepts) with approximately equal currency.
>
> The choice of **abolition** by those working for the **abandonment**, first of
> *slavery*, and then of *capital punishment*, ensured the relative
> supremacy of this member of the pair.

According to
*[French Anti-Slavery:](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=fRQ86zs1A5QC&pg=PR3&source=gbs_selected_pages&cad=2#v=onepage&q=abolition&f=false) The Movement for the Abolition of Slavery in France, 1802–1848,* by Lawrence C. Jennings,

> The first French abolitionist movement centered around the Société des Amis des Noirs. Founded in early 1788 by the journalist Jacques Pierre Brissot and his associate Etienne Clavière, with the close collaboration of Count Honoré de Mirabeau, the Amis des Noirs was inspired by the humanitarianism and egalitarian currents of thought implicit in the eighteenth-century Enlightenment. It was also profoundly influenced from the moment of its inception by the British precedent. The Amis des Noirs was modeled upon the London Society for the Abolition of the Slave Trade, which had been formed in May 1787.

(p. 1)

Contextual needs, however, still leave room for abolishment to be used with fair frequency.

- > He rewrote things to reflect this, now calling for the "**abolishment** of politics".

  ("[Sex-Pol: Essays, 1929-1934 by Wilhelm Reich – review](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2013/may/01/sex-pol-essays-reich-review)", Christopher Turner, *The Guardian,* May 1, 2013.)
- > It's like calling for the **abolishment** of pedestrian crossings because some people skip red lights.

  ("[Theatre bloggers must leave previews alone](https://www.theguardian.com/stage/theatreblog/2011/feb/10/bloggers-review-previews-theatre)", Matt Trueman, *The Guardian,* Feb 10, 2011.)
- > But its **abolishment** “doesn't remove moral and ethical responsibility,” they said in a joint statement.

  ("[Adultery Is No Longer an Affair of the State in South Korea](https://www.nytimes.com/2015/02/27/world/asia/south-korea-strikes-down-adultery-law.html)", Choe Sang-Hun, *The New York Times,* Feb 26, 2015.)
- > As a nation, **abolishment** of slavery was and is an important milestone in our history.

  ("[Ramadan, Day 12: Sex Slavery and Objectification of Women](http://time.com/2964297/ramadan-day-12-sex-slavery-and-objectification-of-women/)", Sohaib N. Sultan, *Time,* July 9, 2014.)

Comment: All four of your examples are from USA media. Can you provide a less biased world view?

Answer (score 1):

The noun *abolition* is a "learned" form that is essentially identical in construction to the Latin noun *abolitio.* For many of the other *-ish* verbs that you mention, there is no corresponding Latin noun ending in *-itio,* so a form in *-ition* would have to be created within English by analogy—something that I think learned individuals would have been reluctant to do in many time periods.

For example, *accomplish* comes from the Old French verb *acumplir/acomplir* (modern French *accomplir*), but in Classical Latin there is no attested verb with the form **accomplire.* The related verb *complere* is attested in Classical Latin, and is the source of the English noun *completion.*

The verb *astonish* seems to be of uncertain origin, but it seems clear that there is no Latin verb **astonire* that could serve as a source for a Latin noun **astonitio.*

The verb *nourish* is from the Latin verb *nutrire,* whence the related noun *nutrition.* But French sound changes may have somewhat obscured the etymological connection between the words *nourish* and *nutrition.*

The verb *vanish* is related to the Latin verb *evanescere,* which is the source of the noun *evanescence.*